# How set select element's first option value to 0 instead of empty option value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to set first option value to 0 instead leaving it blank. How can I set this?
i.e

```
<select id="PatentId" name="ParentId">
     <option value="0">--Select--</option>
     <option value="1">Books</option>
      // other options
</select>
```

My code is as

```
<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.DropDownList("ParentId","--Select--")
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentId)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the following code working

```
private SelectList AddFirstItem(SelectList list)
{
   List<SelectListItem> _list = list.ToList();
   _list.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Value = "0", Text = "--Select--" });
   return new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)_list, "Value", "Text", list.SelectedValue);
}
```

Keep the "Value" and "Text". The Last one `list.SelectedValue` is to keep selected values as it is.

You can use the above function like

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.ParentId = AddFirstItem(new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "Name"));
    return View();
}
```

It worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with the built-in helper. You will have to write a custom helper or hardcode or whatever.

Or simply use a view model and a nullable integer:

```
[Required]
public int? ParentId { get; set; }
```

Now you will no longer have any problems or needs to use 0 as first option.

Also it is better to use the strongly typed version of the helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParentId, Model.Parents, "--Select--")
```

But if for some other reason (which I don't see at the moment) you need to use 0 as first option you are on your own in the wilderness.

Comment: What about adding a [0, "--Select--"] in the `Model.Parents`?

Comment: @Mohayemin, that would indeed be one of the ugly ways to achieve that. I wouldn't do it like this even if it will achieve the desired effect.

Comment: This will not work for me. Because I dont have Child -> Parent relationship in same table. Additionally i tried `public int? ParentId { get; set; }` but did not work

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Ha ha :) Yes that's right. Perhaps I am not matured enough to hate ugly things that much. Perhaps I should learn that ;)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, I am working on one hierarchical structure. i.e Say category - Subcategory. I need to show tree structure. So I need to convert the table data to tree structure. The the function that I am using requires root node to be initially null, when I check it in `if()` condition is says that `can not convert int? to null`

Comment: @RajanRawal, do you know what a Nullable type is in .NET and how to work with them? You need to use the .Value or .HasValue properties on it. As far as the required is concerned, that's because I added the `[Required]` attribute to it thinking that you need to force the user to select a value. If that's not the case simply remove this attribute.

Comment: @RajanRawal, it allows for value types to take null value. It is represented by the `Nullable<T>` generic type structure and manipulated via the .HasValue and .Value properties.

Comment: User omit PatentId. Should I remove `[Required]`

Comment: If it is not required then yes you should remove it. But then if the user doesn't select any value in the dropdown the value of the PatentId property will be null. So it's up to you to handle this.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I have some other queries related to this. Would you please give some time? Please